# Windows 10 Image Configuration Designer. Image creation fails with error "Create catalog failed with hr: 0x80070057"

Tags: windows, installation, deployment, windows-10

I need to create installation image for Windows 10 Enterprise LTSB.

I've installed Windows 10 Imaging and Configuration Designer.

I create a new Image Modification project from install.wim from LTSB ISO. Make no modification to it and press Create -> Production -> To Folder.

Creation fails, error log:

```
8/4/2016 8:23:26 PM Info Project 'Project_8' created successfully and added to workspace
8/4/2016 8:23:28 PM Info Start Imaging Build for Project: Project_8
8/4/2016 8:23:43 PM Error SmiStore::GetSchemaNode (onecore\base\ntsetup\wpx\smi\smistore.cpp:1432) - 0x80070490:
8/4/2016 8:23:43 PM Error     Unattend map doesn't have an entry for /ConnectivityProfiles
8/4/2016 8:23:43 PM Error SmiStore::GetSchemaNode (onecore\base\ntsetup\wpx\smi\smistore.cpp:1432) - 0x80070490:
8/4/2016 8:23:43 PM Error     Unattend map doesn't have an entry for /ConnectivityProfiles
8/4/2016 8:23:43 PM Error SmiStore::GetSchemaNode (onecore\base\ntsetup\wpx\smi\smistore.cpp:1432) - 0x80070490:
8/4/2016 8:23:43 PM Error     Unattend map doesn't have an entry for /Folders
8/4/2016 8:23:43 PM Error SmiStore::GetSchemaNode (onecore\base\ntsetup\wpx\smi\smistore.cpp:1432) - 0x80070490:
8/4/2016 8:23:43 PM Error     Unattend map doesn't have an entry for /Folders
8/4/2016 8:23:43 PM Error SmiStore::GetSchemaNode (onecore\base\ntsetup\wpx\smi\smistore.cpp:1432) - 0x80070490:
8/4/2016 8:23:43 PM Error     Unattend map doesn't have an entry for /ProvisioningCommands
8/4/2016 8:23:43 PM Error SmiStore::GetSchemaNode (onecore\base\ntsetup\wpx\smi\smistore.cpp:1432) - 0x80070490:
8/4/2016 8:23:43 PM Error     Unattend map doesn't have an entry for /ProvisioningCommands
8/4/2016 8:23:43 PM Info InitializeDism: Dism session initialized.
8/4/2016 8:23:43 PM Info CloseDismSession: Dism session closed.
8/4/2016 8:23:43 PM Error SmiStore::GetSchemaNode (onecore\base\ntsetup\wpx\smi\smistore.cpp:1432) - 0x80070490:
8/4/2016 8:23:43 PM Error     Unattend map doesn't have an entry for /ConnectivityProfiles
8/4/2016 8:23:43 PM Error SmiStore::GetSchemaNode (onecore\base\ntsetup\wpx\smi\smistore.cpp:1432) - 0x80070490:
8/4/2016 8:23:43 PM Error     Unattend map doesn't have an entry for /ConnectivityProfiles
8/4/2016 8:23:43 PM Error SmiStore::GetSchemaNode (onecore\base\ntsetup\wpx\smi\smistore.cpp:1432) - 0x80070490:
8/4/2016 8:23:43 PM Error     Unattend map doesn't have an entry for /Folders
8/4/2016 8:23:43 PM Error SmiStore::GetSchemaNode (onecore\base\ntsetup\wpx\smi\smistore.cpp:1432) - 0x80070490:
8/4/2016 8:23:43 PM Error     Unattend map doesn't have an entry for /Folders
8/4/2016 8:23:43 PM Error SmiStore::GetSchemaNode (onecore\base\ntsetup\wpx\smi\smistore.cpp:1432) - 0x80070490:
8/4/2016 8:23:43 PM Error     Unattend map doesn't have an entry for /ProvisioningCommands
8/4/2016 8:23:43 PM Error SmiStore::GetSchemaNode (onecore\base\ntsetup\wpx\smi\smistore.cpp:1432) - 0x80070490:
8/4/2016 8:23:43 PM Error     Unattend map doesn't have an entry for /ProvisioningCommands
8/4/2016 8:23:43 PM Info Exporting customizations as a Provisioning Package to 'C:\Users\Олег\AppData\Local\Temp\ICD_20160804-202343-364_9996.13_556619894.17'
8/4/2016 8:23:43 PM Info Adding runtime settings to Provisioning Package
8/4/2016 8:23:43 PM Info CreateTempDirectory: Create directory: C:\Users\Олег\AppData\Local\Temp\ICD_20160804-202343-381_9996.13_186630994.18
8/4/2016 8:23:43 PM Error SmiStore::GetSchemaNode (onecore\base\ntsetup\wpx\smi\smistore.cpp:1432) - 0x80070490:
8/4/2016 8:23:43 PM Error     Unattend map doesn't have an entry for /ConnectivityProfiles
8/4/2016 8:23:43 PM Error SmiStore::GetSchemaNode (onecore\base\ntsetup\wpx\smi\smistore.cpp:1432) - 0x80070490:
8/4/2016 8:23:43 PM Error     Unattend map doesn't have an entry for /ConnectivityProfiles
8/4/2016 8:23:43 PM Error SmiStore::GetSchemaNode (onecore\base\ntsetup\wpx\smi\smistore.cpp:1432) - 0x80070490:
8/4/2016 8:23:43 PM Error     Unattend map doesn't have an entry for /Folders
8/4/2016 8:23:43 PM Error SmiStore::GetSchemaNode (onecore\base\ntsetup\wpx\smi\smistore.cpp:1432) - 0x80070490:
8/4/2016 8:23:43 PM Error     Unattend map doesn't have an entry for /Folders
8/4/2016 8:23:43 PM Error SmiStore::GetSchemaNode (onecore\base\ntsetup\wpx\smi\smistore.cpp:1432) - 0x80070490:
8/4/2016 8:23:43 PM Error     Unattend map doesn't have an entry for /ProvisioningCommands
8/4/2016 8:23:43 PM Error SmiStore::GetSchemaNode (onecore\base\ntsetup\wpx\smi\smistore.cpp:1432) - 0x80070490:
8/4/2016 8:23:43 PM Error     Unattend map doesn't have an entry for /ProvisioningCommands
8/4/2016 8:23:43 PM Info Adding deployment settings to Provisioning Package
8/4/2016 8:23:43 PM Info Adding file assets to Provisioning Package
8/4/2016 8:23:43 PM Error PackageSecurity::CreateCatalog (onecore\base\ntsetup\provpackageapi\lib\packagesecurity.cpp:368) - 0x80070057:
8/4/2016 8:23:43 PM Error     Invalid catalog path string size
8/4/2016 8:23:43 PM Error ExportProvisioningPackage: Failed with exception Create catalog failed with hr: 0x80070057.
8/4/2016 8:23:43 PM Error CreateFolderDeployment failed, Error: 'Failed to export WimDeploymentProject customizations to a provisioning package.
Create catalog failed with hr: 0x80070057'
8/4/2016 8:23:43 PM Error Failed to create Folder deployment media from Windows image
```

Same happens with Win 10 Enterprise CBB image.

Answer (score 0):

The case is you have your username in Russian (Олег) so it can't create folder in your AppData directory.

Create another English-named user and it will work from there.

Удачи! :)